# How to dynamically increase size of hyperlink in both direction(left and right)?

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the size of hyper-link in both direction(left and right), when text inside changes.

When text inside selected.name changes, it should be expand in both direction. Currently it is expanding in only right direction. I want to expand in both direction when text changes...

HTML

```
<a  ng-model="link_text" class="tag">{{selected.name}}</a>
```

CSS

```
.tag {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #GGGGF0;
  font: 14px/27px'OpenSansLight';
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to remove `float: left` to expand the link in both direction and add following

`min-width:200px; /*optional*/
display:block;
margin:auto;`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try by giving a specific `width` maybe a `min-width` and have `text-align: center;` that should help you with your requirement.